# postgresql - calculating the day of year for the last day of the previous month

Tags: postgresql, date, datepart

I have a query where I'm calculating revenue pace for the year based on revenue so far in the current year. For this calculation, I need to find the doy (day of year) for the last day of the previous month. I know to find the doy for the current date is date_part('doy', current_date). For example, this would be Day 184 for today (July 3, 2023). But I need to calculate for Day 181 (June 30, 2023).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example:

```
select
    date_part('doy',
              date_trunc('month',
                    (current_date - '1 month'::interval)) + ('1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval));

181
```

`current_date - '1 month'::interval` subtracts one month from the current_date. Then [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) truncates that date to beginning of the previous month. 1 month is added to previous month beginning date to get to the first of the current month from which 1 day is subtracted to get the last day of the previous month. at that point `date_part('doy' ...)` is used to get the `doy` for that date.

If you want to find the month end `doy` for some range of dates:

```
select 
    a + ('1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval) AS month_end, date_part('doy', a + ('1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval)) AS doy 
from  
    generate_series('01/01/2023'::date, '12/01/2023'::date, '1 month') as t(a);
        month_end        | doy 
-------------------------+-----
 01/31/2023 00:00:00 PST |  31
 02/28/2023 00:00:00 PST |  59
 03/31/2023 00:00:00 PDT |  90
 04/30/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 120
 05/31/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 151
 06/30/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 181
 07/31/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 212
 08/31/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 243
 09/30/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 273
 10/31/2023 00:00:00 PDT | 304
 11/30/2023 00:00:00 PST | 334
 12/31/2023 00:00:00 PST | 365
```

This uses [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to start a series of month start dates over the desired range. Then it does the date math `date_part('doy', a + ('1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval)) AS doy` to turn the month start dates into month end dates and then convert that date into `doy`.

Comment: Use `EXTRACT(DOY FROM DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) - 'P1D'::INTERVAL)` or `DATE_PART('DOY', DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) - 'P1D'::INTERVAL)` to find the day of the year for the last day of the prior month. There is no value in subtracting and then adding a month.